# Emulating a "OR" condition in Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the Google App Engine with Python (Django).
How to emulate `"SELECT * FROM bla WHERE touser = common.userstats("key") OR fromuser = common.userstats("key") ORDER BY date ASC"`?

I was thinking of something like this, but I can't get it in the order I want.

```
    recievedlist = models.P1.all()
    recievedlist.filter("touser =", common.userstats("key"))
    plus1list = recievedlist.fetch(50)

    sendlist = models.P1.all()
    sendlist.filter("fromuser =", common.userstats("key"))
    plus1list += sendlist.fetch(50)

    # order plus1list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `ListProperty` to your model which contains both `touser` and `fromuser`.  Then you could execute a single query to retrieve the entities which you are interested in sorted by date.  This eliminates a datastore query and the in-memory sort, but costs you an extra index and a little more storage space on your model.

(pseudo) Example:

```
class bla(db.Model):
    ...
    toandfromuser = db.ListProperty(...)
```

Then you can do a query like this (since an entity will match if ANY element of the list `toandfromuser` matches the value you are looking for):

```
SELECT * FROM bla WHERE toandfromuser = common.userstats("key") ORDER BY date ASC
```